# Generate Class-Map including PHPdoc from all classes within a directory

Tags: php

I have a php application build on top of the Laravel framework. All my application specific modules are placed in their own Modules directory `Modules\[Modulname]`.

These modules are autoloaded via PSR-4 in my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "Modules/"
    }
},
```

Is there a way to get an array or something containing all classes, traits and interfaces with all containing methods, attributes and PHPdoc-blocks from the Modules-directory ordered according to the namespace?

I want to build a documentation similar to the [Laravel Api documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/).

Comment: Using `phpdoc`?

Comment: Explanations placed above methods starting with ```/**```

Comment: Do you know what is [`phpdoc`](https://www.phpdoc.org/)?

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for! Do you want to post your comment as answer?